# How do you use common object binding in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

I have a Common Field Object:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string oldName { get; set; }

    private object _Value = null;
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _Value = value;
        }
    }

    private FieldType _fieldType = FieldType.Normal;
    public FieldType FieldType
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldType;
        }
        set
        {
            _fieldType = value;
        }
    }
    private bool _isKey = false;
    public bool IsKey
    {
        get
        {
            return _isKey;
        }
        set
        {
            _isKey = value;
        }
    }
}
```

a Common Record Object:

```
public class Record
{
    public string TableName{get;set;}
    pubilc FieldCollection _fieldcollection = new FieldCollection();
    public FieldCollection FieldCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldcollection;
        }
        set
        {
                _fieldcollection = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The Data from database to convert to Record Object,and then I want to Binding the Record Data to the Control,but it's not working.
I want to know how can I Binding Data like:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", listBox1.DataSource , "BarDesc");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to drag and drop a BindingSource control onto your winform in Design-Time.

Set the BindingSource's DataSource property > Object > Record class. Then set the BindingSource's DataMember.

Select your control (eg Textbox) and set its DataBinding property to the bindingSource control's DataMember.

HTH, at least it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: 3ku but,real field name in The Record.FieldCollection[i].FieldName!
How can I Binding the DataMember：
    public Binding(string propertyName,Object dataSource, string dataMember)

Comment: Its home time for me now, but here's a better answer in case no-one else jumps in: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15596/BindingSource-and-BindingNavigator-in-C-2-0