# How to get a Object element out of the List and add them together

Tags: c#, binding

I need to get the price out of the `List<Ingredient> myIngredient` and into a Label which is on a Windows Form. The code is what I have so far, what would I need to add to make this happen, I've been doing this for days but can't seem to make it happen. When dealing with the Console Applications I was fine but the Window Form are a little tougher..

This is the Windows Form page

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    List<Ingredient> myIngredient = new List<Ingredient>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Cheese", "grams", 3, "grab cheese and sprinkle on top of pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Olives", "grams", 2, "cut up olives and sprickle on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Ham", "grams", 1, "spread cut up ham over pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Pineapple", "grams", 1, "spread cut up chunks over pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Pepperoni", "pieces", 1, "place slices on pepperoni on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Onion", "handfuls", 1, "sprinkle cut up onion on pizza, try not to cry"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Peppers", "grams", 1, "sprinkle cut up peppers on pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Anchovy", "grams", 1, "place on top of pizza"));
        myIngredient.Add(new Ingredient("Mushrooms", "grams", 1, "put gently on top of pizza"));



        foreach (Ingredient pizza in myIngredient)
            if (pizza != null)
            {
                checkedListBoxIngredients.Items.Add(myIngredient);
            }
        checkedListBoxIngredients.DataSource = myIngredient;
        checkedListBoxIngredients.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";



    }


    private void checkedListBoxIngredients_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        string item = checkedListBoxIngredients.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            yourPizza.Items.Add(item);

        }

        else
            yourPizza.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

This is the Class Ingredient

```
    class Ingredient
    {

        public string ToppingName { get; set; }
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionName { get; set; }
    int totalCost;


        public Ingredient(string pizzaToppingName, string pizzaToppingUnit, int pizzaCost, string pizzaDescription)
        {
            ToppingName = pizzaToppingName;
            UnitName = pizzaToppingUnit;
            Cost = pizzaCost;
            DescriptionName = pizzaDescription;
        }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
           return ToppingName + " " + UnitName;
        }
    }

   public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("{0} - {1} ${2:F}", ToppingName, UnitName, Cost);
    }

}
```

Comment: `label1.Text = myIngredient.Sum(x=>x.Cost).ToString()`

Comment: Then how do I bind it to the Window Form? Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: This might help with Binding in winforms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187356/how-do-you-use-common-object-binding-in-winforms-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Well...to get you started - you don't want to add the list items individually to the checkbox list. You want to add your whole list as a data source:

```
public Form1( )
{
  InitializeComponent( );

  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Cheese", "grams", 3, "grab cheese and sprinkle on top of pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Olives", "grams", 2, "cut up olives and sprickle on pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Ham", "grams", 1, "spread cut up ham over pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Pineapple", "grams", 1, "spread cut up chunks over pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Pepperoni", "pieces", 1, "place slices on pepperoni on pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Onion", "handfuls", 1, "sprinkle cut up onion on pizza, try not to cry" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Peppers", "grams", 1, "sprinkle cut up peppers on pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Anchovy", "grams", 1, "place on top of pizza" ) );
  myIngredient.Add( new Ingredient( "Mushrooms", "grams", 1, "put gently on top of pizza" ) );



  checkedListBoxIngredients.DataSource = new BindingSource( myIngredient, null );
  checkedListBoxIngredients.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";

}
```

The BindingSource is the key. You'll want to look that up.

When you bind a list-ish control to a list-ish datasource, you have direct access to the underlying data items referenced by the UI control's list items. For example, you can get the selected ingredients out of the list - say on a button labeled "Order Pizza":

```
private void orderPizza_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{

  var selectedIngredients =
    new List<Ingredient>
    (
      checkedListBoxIngredients
      .CheckedItems
      .Cast<Ingredient>()
    );

  var ingredientPrice = selectedIngredients.Sum( i=> i.Cost );

  //--> complete the order...
}
```